# Can attackers intercept my credentials on an insecure site if I log in through a 3rd party service?

Tags: authentication

I recently visited a forum using non-secure protocol (HTTP) - Chrome flagged a warning at the top saying I shouldn't enter any passwords or personal information onto the site, as they could be intercepted by attackers.

The forum has an option to authenticate via Google. If I use this authentication method without entering my password, can attackers still intercept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably can't intercept credentials, but you might have a problem with tokens if you are using insecure pages and they could potentially authenticate in your name in future instances (as the Facebook Hack of last year).

Answer (score 0):

No, this authorisation method is still secure because OAuth 2.0, which Google uses, [requires TLS to be used when transmitting access tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.3).

However, if the access token is used after authorisation by the site without SSL / TLS, an attacker could intercept the token and gain access to that site.